# Create Statistics / Graphs in SharePoint Lists

Tags: statistics

Is there a way to create Pie Charts from the Information in SharePoint Lists?
I read that they removed the option in SharePoint 2013? Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

There are, and have been, a lot of options to do Dashboarding in SharePoint. At this point in time I would strongly recommend to look into PowerBi to create dashboards based on SharePoint data.

See https://powerbi.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/integrate-power-bi-reports-in-sharepoint-online/ for some samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some JavaScript library for drawing charts. I personally
 recommend [Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js).

Here is an example of pie chart in a Script Editor Web Part that get data from a Tasks list.

```
<canvas id="pieChart" width="150" height="50"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setUpPieChart, "sp.js");
    var splistitemspie = [];
    function setUpPieChart() {
       seriesarray = [];
       var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');
       var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
       splistitemspie = splist.getItems(splistquery);
       currentcontext.load(splistitemspie);
       currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getPieDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, getPieDataFail));
    }

    function getPieDataSuccess(sender, args) {
        var splistitemcount = splistitemspie.get_count();
        var completedCount = 0;
        var noteCompletedCount = 0;
        if (splistitemcount != 0) {
            var splistitemenumerator = splistitemspie.getEnumerator();
            while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
                var status = currentlistitem.get_item("Status");

                if(status == "Completed"){
                    completedCount++;
                }        
                else {
                    noteCompletedCount++;
                }       
            }         

            seriesarray.push(completeCount);
            seriesarray.push(noteCompleteCount);

            drawPieChart(seriesarray);
        }
    }

    function getPieDataFail(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function drawPieChart(seriesarray) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: ["Completed", "Not completed"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Tasks',
                    data: seriesarray,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }
        });
    }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a tutorial? I have a list full of strings and want to create a pie chart for each column